# How can I connect to Active Directory using LDAPS on PHP?

Tags: php, active-directory, openssl, ldap, certificate

I was wondering how to connect to my Active Directory Domain Controller using `LDAPS` in `PHP` on another windows server. 
I have exported the root certificate and the server certificate and put the root in my trusted root store and the server authentication in my personal certificates in my windows certificate store. 
When I try to connect using `port 389` it's fine, but when I try to connect using `port 636` I get an error.

```
 // LDAP variables <br>
 $ldap_host = "myhost";   // your ldap servers<br>
 $ldap_port = 636;          // your ldap server's port number<br>
 $base_dn = "OU=Users,OU=domain,DC=example,DC=local";<br>

// Connecting to LDAP<br>
$connect = ldap_connect( $ldap_host, $ldap_port)<br>
or exit(">>Could not connect to LDAP server<<");<br>
echo "Connected to $ldap_host";<br>

ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);<br>
$ldap_user  = "CN=UserName,OU=No Policy,DC=example,DC=local";<br>
$ldap_pass = "Password";<br>
// verify binding<br>
$bind = ldap_bind($connect, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass)<br>
or exit(">>Could not bind to $ldap_host<<" . ldap_error($connnect) );<br>
```

The output I get is "Connected to myhost Could not bind to myhost. 
When using port 389 I get "connected to myhost"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect to my server using ldaps on PHP using the following method.

```
$connect = ldap_connect('ldaps://'. $ldap_host. ':'. $ldap_port)
```

I also had to create these folders C:\openldap\sysconf and then put a text document named ldap.conf into it. 
I then edited ldap.conf and put in TLS_REQCERT never 
This worked for connecting through LDAPS. 
The correct way to do it, is to download cacert.pem from here: 
 https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
Then add your server hash onto the bottom of this cert. 
 
Lastly edit ldap.conf to say TLS_CACERT \path\to\cert\cacert.pem and comment out the TLS_REQCERT comment from above. 
 
Then restart apache/nginx/etc and you should be able to connect using LDAPS.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `TLS_REQUCERT never` line after you properly installed the certificates. Otherwise you will still not use them and are open for MITM-attacks...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://php.net/ldap_connect) you need to use an LDAP-URI to connect via LDAPS.

In your case that would look like this:

```
ldap_connect('ldaps://'. $ldap_host. ':'. $ldap_port);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've updated my ldap connect to use "ldaps://" in front of my host, but I continue to get the same error as above that I can't bind. I think it has something to do with the certificate verification.

Comment: Is the server using a self signed certificate? And you also included the port in the ldpa_uri?